# get commit informations and changed files from commitID

Tags: git, rest

I want to get the commit information for a given commit id ( instead of entering the commit id on gitlab and search for ex: codeReview ) I want to create a script which takes one or more commitId as parameters and return ( the date , the changed files and components codeReview ... ) .
I dont know if there is an API like REST API to get those informations

Comment: Are you specifically asking about getting this information from GitLab's REST API or is using the Git command line client an option? What are your constraints/requirements? Can't you use `git` on the command line?

Comment: with git commad line I can't get all the information I need , I don't know how to use  GItLab's REST API for such request instead. is there any documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

Would this below help you?

```
git show --stat <COMMIT ID>
```